# What is the origin of the formula: $\rho_x (x)=\left|\frac{{d}x}{{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}\rho_\alpha(\alpha)$ that relates random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, intuition, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the origin of a certain formula used in the solution to the following question:

> This question relates to the position probability density for a
>   classical particle undergoing simple harmonic motion. The particle can
>   be considered to be moving according to the classical trajectory $x =
>  x_0 \sin \omega t$. A measurement is made of the position of the
>   particle at a random time such that the value of the phase $\alpha =
>  \omega t$ can be considered to take any value between $0$ and $2\pi$
>   with equal probability.
>
> Considering $\alpha$ as a random variable, what is its probability density $\rho_\alpha(\alpha)$ and find $\rho_x(x)$ in terms of $x$ only.

```
End of question
```

---

> The probability density for $\alpha$ is uniform between $0$ and $2\pi$
>   so $\rho_\alpha(\alpha)=\cfrac{1}{2\pi}$ within the allowed range.
>
> Finding the derivative of $x$ gives
>
> $\cfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}=x_0 \cos \alpha$
>
> Converting between random variables gives
>
> $\color{red}{\rho_x
>  (x)=\left|\cfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}\rho_\alpha(\alpha)}=\cfrac{1}{2\pi
>  x_0 \color{blue}{| \cos \alpha |}}=\cfrac{1}{2\pi x_0 \sqrt{1-\sin^2
>  \alpha}}=\cfrac{1}{2\pi x_0 \sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}}$

```
End of answer
```

---

I have two simple questions about the answer above:

1. I have never seen the formula (marked red) before and was wondering if someone could explain it's origin and what it means. Below is the formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) although i'm not sure what the inverse phi means or represents.

[image]

2. For the part marked blue; it's obvious $\cos \alpha = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \alpha}$. So why are we considering the **absolute value** of $\cos \alpha$?

Comment: In regards to question 2, can $\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \alpha} < 0$?

Comment: @Axoren No it can't

Comment: Further, can probabilities be negative?

Comment: @Axoren That's a definite no

Comment: @Axoren Probabilities and distribution theory is not my strong point, do you have any idea on the formula marked $\color{red}{red}$?

Comment: This is the formula for [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: @Did Thank you, its under Application in probability right?

Comment: @BLAZE Yes. The difference between that section and your red formula is that the answer key already moved the derivative to the other side.

Comment: @Axoren Answer key?

Comment: @BLAZE wherever you go the solution to the question. I assumed it was from a textbook. It was merely a reference to the solution itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a probability specific concept. Rather, it has to do with the concept of *densities* and their transformation laws.

First, let us write a 1d probability integral in the following equivalent form:

$$P_\alpha(b) - P_\alpha(a) = \int_a^b p_\alpha(\alpha) e^\alpha \cdot e_\alpha \, d\alpha$$

where $e^\alpha \cdot e_\alpha = 1$. From a geometric standpoint, $e_\alpha$ is the vector tangent to the region of integration: this is an important concept in integrals, both 1d and multidimensional. *Every* integral contributes this part, this tangent to the region of integration.

So what is $e^\alpha$? It is the dual vector to $e_\alpha$. In 1d, it is parallel to $e_\alpha$ but reciprocal in magnitude.  In multiple dimensions, it would be formed from the normal to a hypersurface of constant $\alpha$.

It is $p_\alpha(\alpha) e^\alpha$ that is a fundamental, geometric quantity in probability space.

That may seem rather arbitrary, but it is exactly this matter that is cropping up in your problem.  Let's transform to the new coordinate $x$ instead of $\alpha$:

$$P_\alpha(b) - P_\alpha(a) = \int_{a}^{b} p_\alpha(\alpha) e^\alpha \cdot e_\alpha \, d\alpha$$

What happens when we change variable of integration?  Here's the rule: the $e_\alpha \, d\alpha$ changes to $e_x \, dx$.  You might think, "Wait, that's arbitrary, that doesn't make sense! There should be a correction.  I've changed variables in a hundred 1d integrals, and there's always a factor of the Jacobian."  There is and there will be, just not *here*.  What stays fixed is the $e^\alpha$ from the probability density. That's where our Jacobian factor will come from: when we rewrite $e^\alpha$ in terms of $e^x$.

Geometrically, what's going on is this:  go back to the idea of an integral as the limit of a Riemann sum. When we change variables from $\alpha$ to $x$, we're picking up different amounts of length (generally: volume or hypervolume) in $x$ space compared to when we were in $\alpha$ space, but this is entirely captured by the length of $e_x$ vs. $e_\alpha$.

So let's continue:

$$P_x (x(b)) - P_x(x(a)) = \int_{x(a)}^{x(b)} (p_\alpha \circ \alpha)(x) e^\alpha \cdot e_x \, dx$$

Now we can plug in the transformation law, which is well known from the transformation of tensors:  $e^\alpha = \frac{d\alpha}{dx} e^x$. This views $\alpha = \alpha(x)$, but you can turn that into $\frac{dx}{d\alpha}^{-1}$ by the inverse function theorem. Then just use $e^x \cdot e_x = 1$, and you're done.

---

I've given a somewhat involved argument for the change of variables in 1d integration, but I think it's important to emphasize that that rule is *not* arbitrary, nor is it achieved by wanton mathematical voodoo: the rule can be derived by basic reasoning about Riemannian integrals in a geometric picture, and these concepts apply more generally to multivariable calculus.  This should also emphasize the connection between tensor densities and probability densities.

Finally, I think it is very useful to think of $p_\alpha e^\alpha$ as the actual geometric quantity, at least in some situations, as this makes the transformation laws to other coordinates (other random variables) follow automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your rigorous answer, since you have been so helpful in this question I was wondering if you would consider giving [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526922/what-does-the-phi-1-mean-in-this-formula-rho-yy-rho-x-phi-1y) a shot?