# What does the $\phi^{-1}$ mean in this formula: $\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{{d}\phi^{-1}}{{d}y}\right|$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This post is strongly related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523693/what-is-the-origin-of-the-formula-rho-x-x-left-fracdxd-alpha-righ) where I was informed about this formula

$$\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}\right|$$
at the bottom of [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). The problem is that having read the page I still have no idea what the $\phi^{-1}$ represents. But most importantly I would like to know if

$$\rho_x (x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}\tag{A}$$

is the same formula as

$$\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}\right|\tag{B}$$

To give the formulae some context; this post uses **same question** and **same answer** as in my last post:

---

> This question relates to the position probability density for a
>   classical particle undergoing simple harmonic motion. The particle can
>   be considered to be moving according to the classical trajectory $x =
>  x_0 \sin \omega t$. A measurement is made of the position of the
>   particle at a random time such that the value of the phase $\alpha =
>  \omega t$ can be considered to take any value between $0$ and $2\pi$
>   with equal probability.
>
> Considering $\alpha$ as a random variable, what is its probability density $\rho_\alpha(\alpha)$ and find $\rho_x(x)$ in terms of $x$ only.

```
End of question
```

---

> The probability density for $\alpha$ is uniform between $0$ and $2\pi$
>   so $\rho_\alpha(\alpha)=\cfrac{1}{2\pi}$ within the allowed range.
>
> Finding the derivative of $x$ gives
>
> $\cfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}=x_0 \cos \alpha$
>
> Converting between random variables gives
>
> $\color{red}{\rho_x
>  (x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\cfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}}=\cfrac{1}{2\pi
>  x_0 \color{blue}{| \cos \alpha |}}=\cfrac{1}{2\pi x_0 \sqrt{1-\sin^2
>  \alpha}}=\cfrac{1}{2\pi x_0 \sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}}$

```
End of answer
```

---

As shown above the answer uses formula $(\mathrm{A})$

If

$$\rho_x (x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{\color{#F80}{-1}}\tag{A}$$

is the same formula as

$$\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\color{#180}{\phi^{-1}}}{\mathrm{d}y}\right|\tag{B}$$

then why does the ${\color{#F80}{-1}}$ in $(\mathrm{A})$ mean to take the reciprocal, whereas in $(\mathrm{B})$ there is $\color{#180}{\phi^{-1}}$?

Thank you.

Comment: @Did Any Ideas on this one please? The reason I'm asking you is because you were the one that kindly suggested the formula.

Comment: The $-1$ in (A) means $1/\cdots$ while $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\phi$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It's okay, I knew that part thanks. What I'm asking here is are the two formulae the same, if so why?

Comment: The missing bit is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem.

Comment: @Martin Are you talking about $(f^{-1})^{\prime}(f(a))=\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}$?

Comment: @Martin Okay nice work, now we are getting somewhere, thanks that was helpful. Can you please use this theorem in an answer to prove that the formulae are equal? I would do this myself only I am unsure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mostly a tongue twister. Change $x$ and $\alpha$ in (A) to $y$ and $x$ respectively:
$$
\rho_x(x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}\longrightarrow 
\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(x)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|^{-1}
$$
Now, $x = \phi^{-1}(y)$ and
$$
\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(x)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|^{-1} =
\rho_x(x)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\right| =
\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm{d}y}\right|.
$$

Comment: You mentioned that the __inverse function theorem__ is needed, do you know how $(f^{-1})^{\prime}(f(a))=\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}$ is related to $\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}|$?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528328/how-is-the-inverse-function-theorem-used-to-prove-that-the-formulae-in-this-ques?noredirect=1#comment3112424_1528328) is a strongly related question, you might be able to help with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are the same. There is no proof as such because the first formula (using $x$ and $\alpha$) is merely conventional shorthand for the latter.

First, understand that when we write $\rho_x(x) = \ldots$, it means we're talking about a function--$\rho_x$--that takes one parameter, which on the right-hand side will be referred to as $x$.

But the right-hand side of your expression is $\rho_\alpha(\alpha) |dx/d\alpha|^{-1}$.  Does this mean $x$ is a function?  You might say yes, $x$ is a function of $\alpha$, but that, too, doesn't make sense: if we removed all reference to $\alpha$, which we could do, you'd say $x$ should be a real number, not a function.  That is, the single parameter of the function $\rho_x$ should be a real number.

Yet in reality, there's a tendency to play fast and loose with notation. On the left we say $x$ is a real number, but on the right, we treat it as though it is a function of $\alpha$. That is what makes the derivative make sense.  And yet we also say that $\alpha$ is a function of $x$!  $x$ is a function of $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is a function of $x$?  But that's what the notation says: $\rho_\alpha$ is a function of $\alpha$, but $\alpha$ isn't a free parameter from the left-hand side.  It must mean some function $\alpha(x)$.

In other words, common notation is confusing and self-contradictory when you think about it. Writing instead

$$\rho_x(x) = (\rho_\alpha \circ \phi^{-1})(x) |([\phi^{-1}]' (x)|$$

is completely unambiguous.  $\rho_x$ is a function of one parameter.  It is the product of $\rho_\alpha \circ \phi^{-1}$ applied on that parameter and the derivative $(\phi^{-1})'$ applied on that parameter.  Now, the left and right-hand sides are manifestly functions of the same parameter, and they can be considered equivalent.

You might be wondering, "But what about $\alpha$?" Simply compose this function with $\phi$:

$$(\rho_x \circ \phi)(x) = \rho_\alpha(x) |([\phi^{-1}]' \circ \phi)(x)|$$

Now you're thinking, "But that's $x$, not $\alpha$!"

$x$ the function argument?  That is a placeholder.  This is equivalent to

$$(\rho_x \circ \phi)(\alpha) = \rho_\alpha(\alpha) |([\phi^{-1}]' \circ \phi)(\alpha)|$$

This notation admits a simple point of view: the input to a function is just a placeholder variable, of no significance whatsoever, and we "change variables" really by transforming functions.  It seems, at first, a bit antithetical to geometry and coordinates.

If changing variables is a point of view suited for passive transformations (objects stay the same, but coordinates or bases change), then changing functions in this way is a point of view suited for active transformations (objects change, coordinates or bases stay the same).

Of course, both points of view yield the same overall math.

You might now realize that common notation for even very simple, trivial things often imposes double meanings to symbols, as in your problem, $x$ is treated variously as a real-valued parameter and as a function, seemingly changing meanings (or perhaps, taking on all of these meanings) as needed.  I don't actually have a problem with that, as in this problem the meaning of $x$ or $\alpha$ in any given expression can be inferred from context. That's what makes the notation powerful and concise (rather than have to introduce $\phi$, which is of no geometric significance).

Still, in some complicated problems it may be handy to do away with these shortcuts and ensure that every symbol means one, and only one, type of thing, so that the math in front of you is totally unambiguous.