# How is the Inverse function theorem used to prove that the formulae in this question are the same?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

I was informed in my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526922/what-does-the-phi-1-mean-in-this-formula-rho-yy-rho-x-phi-1y/1527004#1527004) that the [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem):

$$(f^{-1})^{\prime}(f(a))=\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}\tag{I*}$$

was needed to show that

$$\rho_x (x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}\tag{A}$$

is the same formula as

$$\rho_y(y)=\rho_x(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}\right|\tag{B}$$

Where $(\mathrm{A})$ and $(\mathrm{B})$ are formulae that relate the probability densities for random variables $x$, $\alpha$ in $(\mathrm{A})$ and $y$ and $x$ in  $(\mathrm{B})$.

It's probably pretty simple to do but I'm not seeing it thus far; So how can I use $(\mathrm{I^{*}})$ to prove equivalence of $(\mathrm{A})$ and $(\mathrm{B})$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite B as
$$\rho_y(y)=\rho_z(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}\right|$$
I just renamed $x$ with $z$ to not mix it with the $x$ in A.

Next, let 
Let $z=\phi^{-1}(y)$ then 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z} =\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}\right)^{-1}=\left(
\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}
\right)^{-1}$$
subsequently $
\left(
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z}
\right)^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}}{\mathrm{d}y}
$. Note also that $|a^{-1}|=\left|\frac{1}{a}\right|=\frac{1}{|a|}=|a|^{-1}$.

Now substitute this result in A with $x=y$ and $\alpha=z$ to get

$$\rho_y (y)=\rho_x (x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}=
\rho_z(z)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}z}\right|^{-1}
=\rho_z(\phi^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi^{-1}\color{blue}{(y)}}{\mathrm{d}y}
\right|\tag{1}
$$

**Note**

Due to a question in comment about where is inverse function theorem where used, I add the following

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}f^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm{d}y}\Bigg|_{y=f(a)}=
(f^{-1})^{\prime}(f(a))=\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}
=\cfrac{1}{
\frac{\mathrm{d}f(a)}{\mathrm{d}a}
}=\left(\frac
{\mathrm{d}f(a)}{\mathrm{d}\color{red}{a}}\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac
{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\color{red}{z}}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please explain which part of your proof uses the Inverse function theorem: $(f^{-1})^{\prime}(f(a))=\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}$?

Comment: in $dy/dz=(dz/dy)^{-1}$

Comment: see the note I just added

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have just two further questions: In $(1)$ marked $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ is $\phi^{-1}$ meant to be $\phi^{-1}(y)$ due to the substitution $z=\phi^{-1}(y)$? In $(2)$, for the part marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ how did you get from $a$ to $z$?

Comment: I have another similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529653/an-application-of-the-inverse-function-theorem) that you may be able to answer.

Comment: 1) yes, 2) $z=f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(f(a))=a$