# An application of the Inverse function theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-explanation, inverse-function-theorem

I have recently come across two formula's that I am unfamiliar with and would like to know if they are both aspects of the same thing:

$$\color{purple}{\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}=f(a)(f^{-1})^{\prime}}\tag{1}$$

$$\rho_x (x)=\rho_\alpha(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ is the [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) and $(\mathrm{2})$ is the formula that relates probability densities for random variables $x$, $\alpha$.

In my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528328/how-is-the-inverse-function-theorem-used-to-prove-that-the-formulae-in-this-ques) I was shown that the Inverse function theorem $(1)$ was needed to prove $(2)$.

However, is it true that

$$\underbrace{\rho_x (x)}_{=\color{purple}{\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}}}=\underbrace{\rho_\alpha(\alpha)}_{=\color{purple}{\displaystyle f(a)}}\overbrace{\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}}^{=\color{purple}{\displaystyle (f^{-1})^{\prime}}}$$

Can someone please explain whether the above statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)=\rho_x (x)=\underbrace{\rho_
\alpha(\alpha)}_{=\color{purple}{\displaystyle \frac{d\rho}{d\alpha}(\alpha)}}\overbrace{\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\right|^{-1}}^{=\color{purple}{\displaystyle \left|\frac{d\alpha}{dx}\right|}}=
\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}(\alpha)\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|
$$

without the absolute value the above is just the chain rule
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

also note that 
$$\left(\frac{dx}{d\alpha}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{d\alpha}{dx}}=\frac{d\alpha}{dx}$$

Comment: Thanks again for your answers; How is it true that $\rho_
\alpha(\alpha)=\color{purple}{\displaystyle \frac{d\rho}{d\alpha}(\alpha)}$?

Comment: this is one of the notations of the derivative, often used for a partial derivative in multi variable calculus

Comment: But $\rho_ \alpha(\alpha)$ is a probability density function, how can this be equal to a derivative?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Absolutely_continuous_univariate_distributions

Comment: Okay, that was helpful thanks. So this means that my statement: $\underbrace{\rho_x (x)}_{=\color{purple}{\cfrac{1}{f^{\prime}(a)}}}=\underbrace{\rho_\alpha(\alpha)}_{=\color{purple}{\displaystyle f(a)}}\overbrace{|\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}|^{-1}}^{=\color{purple}{(f^{-1})^{\prime}}}$ is false? Also, can you please answer the questions in my comment for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528328/how-is-the-inverse-function-theorem-used-to-prove-that-the-formulae-in-this-ques)?

Comment: yes, it was false. will look there.

Comment: Nice work, thanks for your time.